# How to journal command after sudo?

Tags: linux, sudo, logs, systemd-journald, journaling

How to configure Linux to journal all command entered by a user after they use `sudo su -` or `sudo su - username` ?

Answer (score 0):

By default `systemd-journald` logs all events that are happening in the system into a single centralized database in `/run/log`.

You can filter out the log entries made by the user by using "_UID" field.

ex: `journalctl _UID=1000 _COMM=su`
    This will show all the logs associated with the user id 1000.

The journals in the /run/log are non-persistent(cleared off at reboot). For persistence you need to modify the `journald.conf` file.

Go to `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` and uncomment the following line.

```
Storage=auto.
```

Then create a "journal" dir in `/var/log` and reload systemd-journald.
**sudo killall -USR1 systemd-journald**.

Comment: This answer misses the point of the question: to log all commands run in a sudo session